# Uploadify - Paperclip - Rails 3.0.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, uploadify

Im trying to get http://www.uploadify.com/ to work with Ruby on Rails 3.0.3, the files are uploading however im trying to fix the following error message. Any help much appreciated.

> Started POST "/videos/" for 10.170.163.142 at 2011-02-10 16:57:16 +0000
>     Processing by VideosController#create as HTML
>     Parameters: {"Filename"=>"tvshow.avi", "folder"=>"/", "_website_session"=>"BAh7CEkiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFRiIlOTA1OTIwODE1NDNkZDhkYzU2Yjc0MWJhMTdiNWFlZTlJIhBfY3NyZl90b2tlbgY7AEZJIjEvd3dnSjQ3NE83cDQ3SkF0ZXU4alN3dHdkaHl5Wm9vV29XRllBOWc1ajRBPQY7AEZJIgx1c2VyX2lkBjsARmkG--f618cf0d51fe1beebcc03eb200d1b3d023c98757", "/wwgJ474O7p47JAteu8jSwtwdhyyZooWoWFYA9g5j4A"=>"=authenticity_token", "Filedata"=>#>, "Upload"=>"Submit Query"}
>   Completed   in 0ms
>
> ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken):
>     app/middleware/flash_session_cookie_middleware.rb:17:in `call'
>
> Rendered /Volumes/Storage/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (2.8ms)
>   Rendered /Volumes/Storage/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (11.2ms)
>   Rendered /Volumes/Storage/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (20.4ms)

I dont understand whats going on here, why does the file not upload?

```
    require 'rack/utils'

    class FlashSessionCookieMiddleware

      include Rack::Utils

      def initialize(app, session_key = '_session_id')
        @app = app
        @session_key = session_key
      end

      def call(env)
        if env['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] =~ /^(Adobe|Shockwave) Flash/
          params = ::Rack::Request.new(env).params
          env['HTTP_COOKIE'] = [ @session_key, params[@session_key] ].join('=').freeze unless params[@session_key].nil?
        end
        @app.call(env)
      end
    end
```

Comment: have a look here: https://github.com/apneadiving/Pic-upload---Crop-in-Ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this plugin https://github.com/trevorturk/flash_cookie_session which did the job just fine, here is my view

```
<% content_for :head do %>
<link href="/uploadify/uploadify.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/uploadify/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/uploadify/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/uploadify/jquery.uploadify.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<%- session_key = Rails.application.config.session_options[:key] -%>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#video-upload').uploadify({
    uploader        : '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
    cancelImg       : '/uploadify/cancel.png',
    auto            : true,
    multi           : false,
    script          : '/videos/',
    onComplete      : function(a, b, c, response){ eval(response) },
    scriptData      : {
            "<%= key = Rails.application.config.session_options[:key] %>" : "<%= cookies[key] %>",
            "<%= request_forgery_protection_token %>" : "<%= form_authenticity_token %>",
          }
  });   
});
</script>
<% end %>
```

Thanks everyone.

Comment: flash_cookie_session now integrates seamlessly with uploadify-rails 3.1.1.1.  Just include flash_cookie_session in your Gemfile before uploadify-rails and the flash session issue will be handled behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

I've been browsing for a while, finally found this code to use. However, newer Uploadify options are out there. Quick c/p (this is HAML)

**Uploadify 3.1**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
              $('#image-uploader').uploadify({
                swf             : '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
                uploadLimit     : 10,
                auto            : true,
                multi           : false,
                script          : '/videos/',
                onComplete      : function(a, b, c, response){ eval(response) },
                formData        : {
                        '"#{key = Rails.application.config.session_options[:key]}"' : '"#{cookies[key]}"',
                        '#{request_forgery_protection_token}' : '#{form_authenticity_token}',
                      }
              });   
            });
```

This part:

```
cancelImg       : '/images/uploadify/cancel.png',
```

Has moved to the CSS File.

For the sessions, use the flash_cookie_session gem, it is much better than trying to hammer in a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you print your @session_key  in the initialize and make sure that it is correct. The name of the key and its value must identical to what you have in your initializer.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note, on rails 3 I had to add u and encodeURIComponent in order to make it work.

```
{
 "<%= key = Rails.application.config.session_options[:key] %>" : "<%= u cookies[key] %>",
 "<%= request_forgery_protection_token %>" : encodeURIComponent("<%= u form_authenticity_token %>"),
}
```